# Emacs initial anonymous buffer

Tags: emacs

I used to have in my emacs `.init.el` file the following two lines used to inhibit the splash screen and to switch to an anonymous buffer

`(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(switch-to-buffer "**")`

Recently I started using `emacs --daemon` and `emacsclient` and my initial buffer is set to `*scratch*`. I don't want Lisp interaction and the annoying scratch message so I wrote the following line in my `init.el`

`(setq initial-buffer-choice "**")`

The problem is that the new initial buffer is different from the traditional `**` buffer. In fact, when closing emacs, I am prompted to save a file called `**`, while I don't want this kind of behavior, I just want my traditional `**` anonymous buffer.

I know that I can manually set `initial-major-mode` and `initial-scratch-message` and continue to use `*scratch*` but I really would like to use `**` instead.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the `initial-buffer-choice` documentation:

> If the value is nil and ‘inhibit-startup-screen’ is nil, show the
>   startup screen.  If the value is a string, switch to a buffer visiting
>   the file or directory that the string specifies.  If the value is a
>   function, call it with no arguments and switch to the buffer that it
>   returns.  If t, open the ‘*scratch*’ buffer.

You have set the value as a string, so it switches a buffer *visiting the file  that the string specifies*.

You can instead set the value as a function returning the buffer you want selected:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice (lambda () (get-buffer-create "**")))
```

Note that I've used `get-buffer-create`, because if the buffer doesn't exist then the function passed will return `nil`, which can cause problems wwhen creating new frames.